# How to get the height and width of an image when android:minSdkVersion="8"

Tags: android

Normally, I can use the following code to get the width of an image, but it require API level 16.
How to get the height and width of an image when android:minSdkVersion="8"

```
Cursor cur = mycontext.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, "");
string width=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT));
```

Comment: does a method for finding bitmap width or imageview width work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass the option to just decode the bounds to the factory:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

//Returns null, sizes are in the options variable
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image.png", options);
int width = options.outWidth;
int height = options.outHeight;
//If you want, the MIME type will also be decoded (if possible)
String type = options.outMimeType;
```

OR

You can get height and width of `ImageView` by using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` through while this will not give you the exact width and height of the image, for getting the Image width height first you need to get the drawable as background then convert drawable toBitmapDrawable` to get the image as Bitmap from that you can get the width and height like here

```
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawble)imageView.getBackground()).getBitmap();
int w = b.getWidth();
int h = b.getHeight();
```

or do like this way

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = imageView.getDrawingCache();
int w = b.getWidth();
int h = b.getHeight();
```

the above code will give you current `Imageview` sized bitmap like screen shot of device

for only `ImageView` size

```
imageView.getWidth();
imageView.getHeight();
```

If you have drawable image and you want that size you can get like this way

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage);
int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
```