# MediaStore Image width and height null

Tags: android, mediastore

when I crawl through the MediaStore, there are images where the entry for height and weight is null.

The files exist and I can show them with the image browser.

```
Cursor mCursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
if(mCursor != null){
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Log.d("DEBUG","PIC PATH: " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
            Log.d("DEBUG","WIDTH: " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH)));
            Log.d("DEBUG","HEGHT: " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT)));
        mCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    mCursor.close();
}
```

> 09-12 18:17:30.861 13002-13002/com.google.observer D/DEBUG: PIC PATH:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20160813_221335.jpg
>
> 09-12 18:17:30.861 13002-13002/com.google.observer D/DEBUG: WIDTH:
>   null
>
> 09-12 18:17:30.861 13002-13002/com.google.observer D/DEBUG: HEGHT:
>   null

The File has the dimensions: 3366*2988 and I can open it in the file browser.

**EDIT**

I tried it with columns (see answer from Pavneet Singh), but same error. The most pictures works, only a few have this problem:

```
final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH, MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT, MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE};
Cursor mCursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns,null,null,MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
if(mCursor != null){
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Log.d("DEBUG","PIC PATH: " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
            Log.d("DEBUG","WIDTH: " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH)));
            Log.d("DEBUG","HEGHT: " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT)));
        mCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    mCursor.close();
}
```

Comment: could recognize and tell me that those few images without height and width were taken from your phone or you download it from somewhere ? because if media store has the information then it will surely give you like your most of images otherwise seems like you few images don't have the details you required

Comment: The example pic is from my instagram folder. When I look the details from the picture with my file explorer (ES File Explorer) it shows me width and height. When the media store cant fetch the information, the only solution is to use BitmapFactory or?

Comment: yeah the alternative approach it `bitmapfactory`  but obviously a little extra processing plus like i said the images causing the problems are aliens from outside,try link in updated answer ,will guide :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaStore` don't return all the columns values automatically due to performance reasons as mentioned in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) so you need to explicitly pass the projection to `MediaStore` query.

```
final String[] columns = {
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT
    };


Cursor mCursor = _context.getContentResolver().
                     query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                          columns,null,null,
                          MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

Some find it confusing but it enhance the performance because there can be too much details related with an image like Date, Time, Title, Place, Latitude, Longitude etc which will degrade the performance if the query is for all images stored(usually it is plus can be thousands of images ) so hence less data, less time hence better performance.

**Details** : Some images might not have the required information maybe they are from another app or downloaded from some site etc so use the update info.

**Update** : you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860675/how-to-get-the-height-and-width-of-an-image-when-androidminsdkversion-8) approach for your few problematic images

Comment: Why you use for the DATA Parameter the MediaStore and for width and height strings?

Comment: this is the standard format because column names needs to be given like this ,consider a regular sql query which is  like `select stu_name,stu_class from tbl_student`

Comment: they should work fine or other constant will work fine too having the same string value , i am not on IDE so that was little quick for me :p , let me edit the answer

Comment: The solution don't works for me I added the columns (see edit in my question) but some pictures have a null at width and height.